# Solr search not returning content type

Tags: search

I have a [site](https://mcmurdohistory.lternet.edu/content) set up with Solr search. Drupal says 100% of the site is indexed, and the Search appears to work for most content types and their fields. However, the search does not seem to be searching all fields of the "Publications" Content Type.

For example, the second item in the [list of publications](https://mcmurdohistory.lternet.edu/content?f[0]=type%3Abiblio) (Title = "Bibliography of dry valleys...") has the following text in the "Bibliographic Citation" field:

> Mead, Kay L. Bibliography of dry valleys publications produced under
>   the aegis of the New Zealand Antarctic Research Program 1959-1976 1977

However, when I search "Mead" in the Solr search I get "no results found". The same with "overseas", which appears in the abstract of the publication.

Yet, if I search "aegis" which appears in the title, the publication is returned.

How can I get Solr to index the other fields?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell Search API exactly what it should index:

1. Go to Admin -> Configuration -> Search and metadata -> Search API
2. For the relevant index, choose "Fields" from the drop down
3. Add your desired field(s) to the index and configure appropriate data types
4. Re-index all content

Comment: It looks like this is already the case.The box for field "Bibliographic Citation" is checked indicating it's indexed, the Type is set to "Fulltext" and "Boost is set to 1.0. Could it be something else?